# Why is matrix not a different field altogether?

Tags: matrices, field-theory, definition

According to Wikipedia-

> In mathematics, a field is a set on which addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are defined, and behave as when they are applied to rational and real numbers.

Now, when we work with matrices we define *addition,subtraction,multiplication* operations (not *division*) on matrices.

So,going by the above definition, does a matrix qualify to be a field as we define the mentioned operations on them?

I have two doubts-

- The definition mentions "...a field is a **set**..." . I know a set is any well defined collection of numbers. A matrix is also a collection of numbers but not well defined. Is this a reason why we cannot call a matrix a set?
- Division of matrices is not defined. Is this also a reason that eliminates the possibilities of a matrix to be called a set?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

1. A matrix is definitely not a set of its entries, but ***all*** matrices of a specified size over a specified field ***is*** a set. This is what we call "the set of matrices".
2. Indeed, this set does not form a field, by two reasons:

   1. Matrix multiplication is not commutative: in general, $AB \neq BA$.
   2. In a field, all non-zero elements are invertible. This is not the case for matrices: a matrix $A$ is invertible only if $\det A$ is invertible (is not zero, if the scalars form a field), and there do exist non-zero matrices with zero determinant.

So, the structure that the set of matrices forms is a non-commutative ring.

Comment: Does *invertible* mean *division* in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @tatan Invertible means $\exists \frac{1}{x}$ in the ring of scalars. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$ all non-zero elements are invertible. However, in $\mathbb Z$ only $\pm 1$ are invertible, and a matrix with integer coefficients is invertible (with the inverse also having integer coefficients) iff its determinant is $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the set of all matrices is not a field.

There are many problems with the matrices which keep it far from being a field.

Even if we consider the set of all invertible  $n\times n$ matrices along with the $n\times n$ matrix of $0$  we still do not have a field.

The big problem is that even if $AB$ and $BA$ are defined, we do not have $AB=BA$ for all $A$ and $B$.